# Quad core vs. 8 core and Protools HD

Tags: pro-tools

Hi all

So a week ago my old dual 1.8 g5 mac died. I briefly panicked and didnt know what to do. Called a dealer and was told that HDX was coming at AES. 
Now Im on the search for a new mac that in time, most likely will house the HDX PCIe card, and PT10HD. Because of the very steep crossgrade price, Im forced to cut the costs where I can.
I was wondering if any of you are running Protools HD (maybe 9?) on a quad core mac (2010 model), with either HD Accel cards or Natively, and if you find it to have enough juice for non dsp tasks, RTAS plugs and so on. Also of it is playing along nicely, together with PT.
8 core users, and everybody else, are most welcome to chime in with their knowledge too.

Im uncertain if a quad will have enough power, to playback surround sesions, edits, automation and have a bunch of native plugs inserted etc.

Thanks alot

Best wishes

Mikkel

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an HD system. But I bought the smallest MacPro (Quad 2.8 I think) last year running PT9 with CPTK. So everything is native on this machine.

Though I'm working in bigger studios a lot, I use the system in my own room to do all kinds of stuff. E.g. sound design for a feature last year with a setup that was intended to mimic a HD3 system in terms of busses and I/Os. This was for the ambience and effects session, which I also premixed on my own system before moving to the mixing stage. Even with the small 3GB onboard RAM I had no trouble so far.

In regards to 10 I hope that stuffing it full with RAM will make my Mac a nice though small work horse.

Answer (score 0):

I've been hearing that the 6-core Mac Pros fare better than the 8-cores when it comes to Pro Tools. Something about how Pro Tools like faster cores better than more cores. Might not be true, but I've seen 6 cores run huge surround sessions.

Comment: Thanks alot max. I wish i could afford a 6 core, or an 8 core. Budget will "only" be for a quad though. 
Thanks again. 

Comment: I'll second this - with each additional core, you generally get diminished returns for macs and for pc.  It's one of the reasons I still run a quad core.  It's much better, with most applications, to get faster cores rather than more cores.  However, I don't run PT so take that for what it's worth =)

Answer (score 0):

So I bought a Quad to go with the HDX card. Couldnt be happier.
Everything works flawlessly (so far....)

I can see why you should go with an 8core or more if going native, but with my HDX card onboard Im safe.
Still able to run a big amount of native plugs, like Altiverbs etc. Dosent take up to much cpu.

Thanks all:)